# nodo enlazado de tipo dinámico con templante c++

Tags: c++, lista

Hace poco me he dado a la tarea de crear mi propia librería de lista de objetos dinámicos, he encontrado frameworks de trabajo como Qt y Boost, y tienen ya implementadas librerías como [Qvariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) y [boost::variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/variant.html), estoy muy interesado en el desarrollo de apps de consola, y soy relativamente nuevo en el lenguaje, hasta ahora para esto he creado una estructura que maneje los punteros de los nodos

```
struct nodoBase
{
    virtual ~nodoBase() = default;
    nodoBase* next;
    nodoBase* prev;
};
```

y luego creo con una plantilla la estructura nodo

```
template <class T>
struct Nodo : public nodoBase
{
    T value;
};
```

Sin embargo a partir de esto cuando creo mi nodo no puedo acceder a los valores, a continuación un ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    Nodo<int> Nint;
    Nint.next = new Nodo<char>;
    Nint.value = 6;

    Nint.next->value;
    return 0;
}
```

El error que obtengo : 'struct nodoBase' has no member named 'value'
mas que la solución al problema también me gustaría recibir alternativas de diseño.

De antemano muchas gracias quedo atento a cualquier respuesta o comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ es un lenguaje que posee tipado fuerte. Esto quiere decir que el compilador debe saber, en todo momento y sin lugar a dudas, el tipo de todas las variables que está manejando.

Este detalle tiene implicaciones en tu proyecto, ya que **no es posible** ofrecer de forma genérica diferentes tipos en `value`. En algún punto de tu código tendrás que poner código específico que sea capaz de identificar el tipo de nodo que estás tratando para extraer de dicho nodo su valor.

De forma nativa, puedes descubrir el tipo real de nodo apuntado usando `dynamic_cast`:

```
if( auto nodoInt = dynamic_cast<Nodo<int>>(Nint.next) )
{
  // Nint.next es de tipo Nodo<int>
  std::cout << nodoInt->value;
}
else if( auto nodoLong = dynamic_cast<Nodo<long>>(Nint.next) )
{
  // Nint.next es de tipo Nodo<long>
  std::cout << nodoLong->value;
}
```

Hoy en día `dynamic_cast` está bastante optimizado y tiene poco *overhead*, aunque algo sí que tiene.

Otro gallo cantaría si la acción a realizar fuese genérica, es decir, por ejemplo, volcar el valor a un stream o leerlo del mismo. En este caso puedes usar una función virtual.

Al sobreescribir la función en la clase derivada consigues que se ejecute ese código aunque el puntero sea de una clase padre:

```
struct nodoBase
{
    virtual ~nodoBase() = default;
    virtual void read(std::istream & is) = 0;
    virtual void write(std::ostream & os) = 0;
    nodoBase* next;
    nodoBase* prev;
};

template <class T>
struct Nodo : public nodoBase
{
    T value;

    void read(std::istream & is) override
    { is >> value; }

    void write(std::ostream & os) override
    { os << value; }
};

Nodo<int> nodoInt;
NodoBase* nodo = &nodoInt;

nodo->read(std::cin);
nodo->write(std::cout);
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CGgVnEc8MvQJMI8Z)

También, si el número de tipos que va a soportar la lista es limitado y conocido de antemano, puedes crear una adaptación del patron *visitor*:

```
template<class T> struct Nodo;

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void Visit(Nodo<int> * nodo) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Nodo<long> * nodo) = 0;
};

struct nodoBase
{
    virtual ~nodoBase() = default;

    virtual void Accept(Visitor& visitor) = 0;

    nodoBase* next;
    nodoBase* prev;
};

template <class T>
struct Nodo : public nodoBase
{
    T value;

    void Accept(Visitor & visitor) override
    { visitor.Visit(this); }
};

struct VisitorImprimirTipo : Visitor
{
    void Visit(Nodo<int> * nodo) override
    {
      std::cout << "Nodo<int> -> " << nodo->value << '\n';
    }

    void Visit(Nodo<long> * nodo) override
    {
      std::cout << "Nodo<long> -> " << nodo->value << '\n';
    }
};

Nodo<int> nodoInt;
nodoInt.value = 10;
Nodo<long> nodoLong;
nodoLong.value = 123;

nodoBase* nodo = &nodoInt;
nodo->next = &nodoLong;

VisitorImprimirTipo visitor;
nodo->Accept(visitor);
nodo->next->Accept(visitor);
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/olKzNlCgbZvyFpwj)

Alternativas hay muchas, pero todas, en algún momento, te llevan a saber cual es el tipo concreto de nodo.